# SCNSceneRenderer presentScene with SKTransition from CIFilter crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in jet_context::set_fragment_texture

Tags: ios, scenekit, core-image

I'm currently trying to transition between two scenes in SceneKit with a custom transition animation. The appropriate `SCNSceneRenderer` method takes an `SKTransition` like so:

```
self.presentScene(scene,
    withTransition: SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.blackColor(), duration: 0.5),
    incomingPointOfView: scene.cameraNode,
    completionHandler: nil)
```

The code uses one of the build-in transitions and works fine. In order to create a custom transition, one needs to initialize the `SKTransition` with a `CIFilter` that, according to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTransition_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTransition/transitionWithCIFilter:duration:), takes two input images, a time parameter and creates a single output image. Some of the predefined filters meet these requirements, e.g. `CIDissolveTransition`:

```
self.presentScene(scene,
    withTransition: SKTransition(CIFilter: CIFilter(name: "CIDissolveTransition")!, duration: 0.5),
    incomingPointOfView: scene.cameraNode,
    completionHandler: nil)
```

But this crashes with an extremely unhelpful EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I even created a simple prototype with an image view and a slider that crossfades two images with the same filter to verify that it works as expected (it does). I'm tearing my hair out here. Am i missing something?

**edit** StackOverflow has marked this question as a possible duplicate and asked me to explain myself. Hence, to clarify: I do **not** have a problem with presenting the scene but with presenting the scene **using an `SKTransition` initialized with a `CIFilter`**.

**edit 2** Additional info: It only crashes on Metal. When forced to render with OpenGL it does not crash, but it doesn't animate the transition either.

**edit 3** Tried this again on another device, now i'm getting the trace for `jet_context::set_fragment_texture` in addition to the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SceneKit presentScene(\_withTransition:incomingPointOfView completionHandler) crash with dynamically loaded SCNScene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482115/scenekit-presentscene-withtransitionincomingpointofview-completionhandler-cra)

Comment: The bug number I filed on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482115/scenekit-presentscene-withtransitionincomingpointofview-completionhandler-cra is rdar://24012973, should you care to dupe it at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Your problem seems to be with presenting the scene, which works fine for me, as long as i use one of the build-in SKTransitions. I think these are two separate issues.

Comment: Just filed a radar myself. rdar://24425404

Comment: Same issue here. Works perfectly with `SKTransition.fadeWithColor(UIColor.blackColor(), duration: 0.5)` but there is no actual transition if it is `CIFilter(name: "CIDissolveTransition")` or other CIFilter. Scene presentation works, but it just freezes for the time of duration...